# Can I run Docker with SSL/TLS but no certificate?

Tags: ssl, docker, amazon-ec2, tls1.2

I want to run a docker container on an Ubuntu 16.04 server, using SSL to secure the client communication. All of the docs that I have found indicate that I have to use certificates to do this, rather than a simple public/private key pair. Unfortunately, my server is based on Amazon AWS, which does not permit certificates to be created. Can I simply use SSL with keys instead?

Comment: Can you use a self-signed cert?

Comment: I tried that but when the certificate creation process tries to contact the amazon url, it gets an error code back from the aws server, indicating that certificates are not permitted.